# Finding the most common text value in a table column while filtering based on another column

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with a list of purchase orders which contain the supplier name and the type of commodity sold. I want to create a new list with the most common commodity for each supplier. List 1 below is what I have now, and list 2 is what I want to see.

```
list 1
SupplierA Food
SupplierB Food
SupplierA Computers
SupplierA Food
SupplierB Computers
SupplierB Computers

list 2
SupplierA Food
SupplierB Computers
```

I think the solution will have a combination of index, mode, match, and if formulas but do not know how to put these together.

Comment: Do you have Supplier & Commodity in a different column somewhere? If not I can't think of how to do this in just a formula. It would be pretty simple to write a vba script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS(B:B,$B$1:$B$6,A:A,D1)),COUNTIFS(B:B,$B$1:$B$6,A:A,D1),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

It can also be done with this array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$6,MODE(IF($A$1:$A$6=D1,MATCH($B$1:$B$6,$B$1:$B$6,0))))
```